# Proving an equation has a unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that $ a^2-2ax+(2ax-a^2N)e^{(-a/x)}=0$ has a unique solution.

(Note: $x>0, a>0, N$:positive integer). Thanks.

Comment: Is $a$ a constant?

Comment: Yes,$a$ and $N$ are constants. $x$ is variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = a -2x +(2x-aN) e^{-a \over x}$. $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( a(1-Ne^{-a \over x}) + 2x(e^{-a \over x} - 1)\right)= -a(1+N)$ (using l'Hôpital), $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) = a>0$.

$f'(x) = -e^{-a \over x} \left( {{a}^{2}N+2{x}^{2}{e}^{\frac{a}{x}}-2{x}^{2}-2ax \over x^2} \right)$.

For positive $x$, we have $2x^2(e^{a \over x}-1) \ge 2 ax$, hence $f'(x) < 0$. The result follows.

Comment: That was sloppy of me.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt solution. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The equation represents the intersection of two monotone functions $$f(x)=\frac{2ax-a^2}{2ax-a^2N}=\frac{2x-a}{2x-aN}$$ $$g(x)=e^{-a\over x}$$ You find $f(0)=\frac{1}{N} \gt 0$ and $g(0)=0$. On the other side, the derivatives are  $$f'(x)=-\frac{2 a (n-1)}{(2 x-a n)^2} \lt 0$$ $$g'(x)=\frac{a e^{-\frac{a}{x}}}{x^2} \gt 0$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Another approach. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are very welcome ! Cheers :)